# bluemix visual insights vs visual recognition modules

Tags: image, ibm-cloud

Can someone tell me the difference (or if they're synonymous or one supersedes the other) between the BlueMix [Visual Insights](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/visual-insights/) module and the [Visual Recognition](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/visual-recognition/) module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy now.   Visual Recognition replaces Visual Insight.  https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2016/06/03/visual-recognition-api-launch-visual-insights-deprecation/

Answer (score 2):

Visual Recognition allows users to understand the semantic contents of an image or video frame. It takes as input JPEG images and it can use pre-trained or custom models.
Visual Insights extracts consumer insights related to interests, activities and so on starting from a set of images (provided as an input archive). It provides as output clusters or groupings of images based on visual appearance (as you can see in [this](https://visual-insights-demo.mybluemix.net/?cm_mc_uid=11335133656114562151633&cm_mc_sid_50200000=1459804258) demo).

If you need to retrieve semantic information in a single image, training your own classifier, you should probably choose Visual Recognition. If you need to calculate a score as combination of confidence and prevalence ranging from low to high in a collection of images, you should probably use Visual Insights.

Visual Insights is an experimental service and it is not recommended for production use. Moreover it might change in the future.
An experimental service has no support, while Visual Recognition is directly supported by IBM Watson team if you open a support ticket from Bluemix.